# Use truststore & keystore at ClientSSLSecurity method in strong-soap(JavaScript)

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, ssl-certificate

I am consuming a SOAP web service from NodeJs application, using strong-soap library. I am able to generate the client from WSDL where I can see all the methods of given SOAP service, I need to pass SSL certificates along with method invocation. 
I have given two JKS file (Truststore.jks and Keystore.jks).

Not sure which should go where according to below code snippets?

This is code snippets given by strong-soap github page.

```
client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(
    '/path/to/key'
    , '/path/to/cert'
    , {/*default request options*/}
  ));
```

I have modified this using following way -

```
client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(
     /certs/keystore.jks'
    , '/certs/truststore.jks'
    , {/*default request options*/}
  ));
```

Getting “tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=503”.

**Not sure, which JKS file should be used for what? 
Which one is key and which one is cert?**